# Change parent in childs of another parent

Tags: javascript, html

i am new in js and i have problem. I have this html markup :

```
<div id="searchBar">
  <div>
    <a>some link </a>
    <span>some text </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

and after use js script i want to get this :

```
<div id="searchBar">
  <div>
    <div class="toplink_bl">
      <a>some link </a>
      <span>some text </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but something wrong and i get this:

```
<div id="searchBar">
  <div>
      <a>some link </a>
      <span>some text </span>
      <div class="toplink_bl"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is js code :

```
 var toplink_div=document.createElement('div');
 toplink_div.className="toplink_bl";
 $(toplink_div).appendTo($("#searchBar div"));
 for(var i = 0; i < $("#searchBar div").childNodes.length; i++) {
  toplink_div.appendChild($("#searchBar div").childNodes[i]);
 };
```

**UPD:**
[@Ricky Stam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1961333/ricky-stam), thank you, it works! Can u help with same problem but with some additional? I added new line in your code :

```
<div id="searchBar">
  <div class="inner">
    <a>some link </a>
    <span>some text </span>
    <input type="text" class="searchInput" value="" name="q" id="keywords" tabindex="1">
  </div>
</div>
```

And i want that `<div class='new'>` include two elements `<a>` and `<span>` but not `<input>`.
So after use `$( ".inner" ).wrapInner( "<div class='new'></div>");` it must be like this :

```
<div id="searchBar">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class='new'>
      <a>some link </a>
      <span>some text </span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="searchInput" value="" name="q" id="keywords" tabindex="1">
  </div>
</div>
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Try $(".searchInput").appendTo(".inner")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML

```
<div id="searchBar">
  <div class="inner">
    <a>some link </a>
    <span>some text </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$( ".inner" ).wrapInner( "<div class='new'></div>");
```

This will put everything inside "inner" div inside a div with class="new".

Comment: Sory for this cooment. Can u help me with problem in updated part of question?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [prependTo](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/) instead.

Following their example, this:

```
<h2>Greetings</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

With this code:

```
$( "<p>Test</p>" ).prependTo( ".inner" );
```

Results in this:

```
<h2>Greetings</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>Test</p>
    Hello
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <p>Test</p>
    Goodbye
  </div>
</div>
```

So change your code like that:

```
 var toplink_div=document.createElement('div');
 toplink_div.className="toplink_bl";
 $(toplink_div).prependTo($("#searchBar div"));
 for(var i = 0; i < $("#searchBar div").childNodes.length; i++) {
  toplink_div.apendChild($("#searchBar div").childNodes[i]);
 };
```

Here you can see it running: http://jsfiddle.net/WRWy5/1/

Comment: OP don't want to append or to prepend something he wants to Wrap something

Comment: @RickyStam I understood he want `prependTo` `#searchBar div` his `toplink_div`.